# How to save file to external storage properly in Android?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-storage

I would like to create a zip file and save it to external storage. Any external folder would do. The old way is using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but that has been deprecated. It throws exception on API 30. The new way is using `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, but that is only available since API 29. So basically I need to write the code twice with an if statement, if I want my app to work on all API levels:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
   // Do it the new way.
} else {
   // Do it the old way.
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `It throws exception on API 30` No. Not al all. It gives a nice File instance as it used to be.

Comment: I got `java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted` even the app has `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` runtime permission. What did I do wrong?

Comment: We dont know what you did. But calling getExternalStorageDirectory() does not throw exeptions.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
try {
        File yourFileToSave = /* You find your file to work with here */;

        File storedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "storedFileName.jpg");
        storedFile.createNewFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourFileToSave);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) yourFileToSave.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(data,0,data.length);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(storedFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is similar to what I use to store bitmaps, but I had to adjust it a bit for you. The key here is to use context.getCacheDir() to find a suitable directory for your app to store files in. Files in the cache directory can get deleted if the system require more space which can be good since you may end up with a lot of stored files that are never used, but if your file is important you should perhaps find another location like context.getFilesDir() or getDataDir().

Don't forget to ask for permissions both in the AndroidManifest and also ask for runtime permissions.